# How to open socket between Linux PCs in different homes?

Tags: sockets

Could you please explain how to write a C/C++ program that opens a socket from a Linux PC at one home to another Linux PC at another home and sends a text string, in case both PCs are connected to the internet via some internet provider(s) through a router/modem/etc. (assume it is the same program running on both PCs).

Comment: Programming question don't really belong on **this** Q&A site. But even on other [se] sites you will have a problem getting such a generic question answered. There are many things involved in what you want to do, including difficult ones like how the computers know about each other. I recommend you try and look at some open source program source that does close to what you want, (a chat program e.g.) first at a concept level, then in more detail.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)